# Can scrapers block the hotlink protection?

Tags: hotlinking

I have added hotlink protection via htaccess, my cpanel and a plugin (the wp all in one security plugin) but sites are still hotlinking my images.
For example, on this page:[spammy site hotlinking to my site](http://digital-s.info/lena/e/emotion-chart-for-adults.html)

The "list of feelings" on the top left of the page is hotlinking to the list of feelings on my site despite the hotlink prevention. They have a few hundred hotlinks to my site from their spammy site which is why I am trying to stop this.

How do they manage to override the hotlink protection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe because they use an indirect link (via `http://editpower.club`) to show your image?

Comment: Is there a way to prevent hotlinking via an indirect link?

Comment: Sorry, it's not my cup of tea. But I think you can define in your .htaccess to only allow hotlinks from your own site, or others you trust. F.e. [this site](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/) can generate an example.